# difference between pandas statistical functions and boost::accumulators

Tags: python, c++, pandas, boost

I am getting different results for statistics calculations using `pandas` and `boost::accumulators`, and am unsure why.

I have below a simple example using pandas to calculate mean and variance from some returns

```
import pandas

vals = [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1 ]
rets = pandas.Series(vals).pct_change()

print(f'count:    {len(rets)}')
print(f'mean:     {rets.mean()}')
print(f'variance: {rets.var()}')
```

The output of this is:

> ```
> count:    12
> mean:     0.19696969696969696
> variance: 0.6156565656565657
> ```

I am doing the equivalent in C++ using `boost::accumulators` for the stats calculations

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/count.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/variance.hpp>

namespace acc = boost::accumulators;

int main()
{
    acc::accumulator_set<double, acc::stats<acc::tag::count,
                                            acc::tag::mean,
                                            acc::tag::variance>> stats;

    double prev = NAN;
    for (double val : { 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1 })
    {
        const double ret = (val - prev) / prev;

        stats(std::isnan(ret) ? 0 : ret);

        prev = val;
    }

    std::cout << std::setprecision(16)
              << "count:    " << acc::count(stats)    << '\n'
              << "mean:     " << acc::mean(stats)     << '\n'
              << "variance: " << acc::variance(stats) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

> ```
> count:    12
> mean:     0.1805555555555556
> variance: 0.5160108024691359
> ```

- Why are the mean and variance between pandas and boost::accumulators different?
- What do I need to do to get the pandas result from boost::accumulators?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/accumulators/issues/26

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/accumulators/issues/25

Comment: If you clone the head of boost.math, you can use boost/math/tools/univariate_statistics.hpp, which will get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas it will remove `nan` column when you do `mean` by defualt , if we fill `nan` as 0 , the out put is same , since you do `pct_change` , the first item should be NaN

```
rets.mean()
Out[67]: 0.19696969696969696

rets.fillna(0).mean()
Out[69]: 0.18055555555555555
```

---

About `var` make the freedom to 0

```
rets.fillna(0).var(ddof=0)
Out[86]: 0.5160108024691358
```

Comment: I'm still getting a different result for variance: `rets.fillna(0).var()` --> `0.5629208754208754`

Comment: @SteveLorimer sorry just get time reply `rets.fillna(0).var(ddof=0)
` you need add freedom to 0 default 1

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it's possible to go the other way? ie: get `ddof=1` result from `boost::accumulators`?

Comment: @SteveLorimer this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712756/statistics-wiht-large-amount-of-data-in-c-or-scilab-or-octave-or-r